# Batch Recursive For Loop and non-ASCII characters in Folder Namers

Tags: batch-file

This is my continuing attempt to build a filename format verification batch routine ([batch variable exclamation points used in dir | findstr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286676/))
Here's where I'm at:

```
echo off
REM Ensure filenames are of the format ALBUM - TITLE
chcp 1254>nul
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /p CUTOFFDATE=Enter the Date of the Last Cleanup (yyyymmdd):
for /r "\\kodi-pc\g\itunes\iTunes Media\Podcasts\American Civil War\" %%i in (*.mp3) do (
set "FILENAME=%%~nxi"
set "FILEDATE=%%~ti"
call set "TITLE=%%FILENAME:* - = - %%"
call:SETALBUM
call set "FILEDATE=%%FILEDATE:~6,4%%%%FILEDATE:~0,2%%%%FILEDATE:~3,2%%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if !FILEDATE! GTR !CUTOFFDATE! (
    echo ~ALBUM~TITLE~FILENAME~ ~!ALBUM!~!TITLE!~!FILENAME!
    )
endlocal
)
pause
exit /b

:SETALBUM
call set "ALBUM=%%FILENAME:%TITLE%=%%"
exit /b
```

Works great except where folder names contain non-ASCII characters (», ’, etc.). My effort has been to recognize bangs (!) but that accomplished I now have these other problems.

The foldername 'American Civil War' is merely a sample placeholder for this forum. In reality I loop through many hundreds of foldernames.

Thx.

Comment: This line of code is not doing what you think it does. `if %%FILEDATE%% GTR %%CUTOFFDATE%%`.  Those variables will never expand to values.

Comment: Thx you're right. It was a leftover from earlier attempts. I'll have to remember how I did that. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Fixed the date checking lines per squashman

Comment: Answer was found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813495 use chcp 65001 Thx all